# SQL - how to count (number) rows every time a value in one column changes?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, rank

I've seen similar questions asked but nothing exactly like this and haven't been able to figure it out on my own. In my example table below, the first three columns already exist in a calendar table I use to reference the intricacies of my company's fiscal calendar. I will order by transaction_dt from earliest to latest date. The 4th column, "count_column", is what I want to add - simply a column that counts upwards from 1 every time the fiscal_week changes.  I want it to also ignore when the fiscal_week resets to 1 with every new calendar year.  I want count_column to count upwards beginning with 1 and never reset, just keep counting up for as long as new weeks are added to this table.

Makes sense? I feel like this should be simple to do but I can't crack it.  Thanks in advance.

| transaction_dt | fiscal_week | fiscal_year | count_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-28 | 52 | 2020 | 1 |
| 2020-12-29 | 52 | 2020 | 1 |
| 2020-12-30 | 52 | 2020 | 1 |
| 2020-12-31 | 52 | 2020 | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 | 52 | 2020 | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 | 52 | 2020 | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 | 52 | 2020 | 1 |
| 2021-01-04 | 01 | 2021 | 2 |
| 2021-01-05 | 01 | 2021 | 2 |
| 2021-01-06 | 01 | 2021 | 2 |
| 2021-01-07 | 01 | 2021 | 2 |
| 2021-01-08 | 01 | 2021 | 2 |
| 2021-01-09 | 01 | 2021 | 2 |
| 2021-01-10 | 01 | 2021 | 2 |
| 2021-01-11 | 02 | 2021 | 3 |

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you’re using

Comment: One question is whether this column is one you want to populate on insert (I think that is what you are saying) or whether you have a table with the three columns and want a query that will provide the four columns with the fourth correctly calculated. If it's the former one way (probably not the most elegant is a trigger along the lines of (in pseudo-plsql) `select fiscal_week, count_column into max_week, max_count from table order by transaction_date desc fetch first 1 rows only; :new.count_column := case when :new.fiscal_week = max_week then max_count else max_count+1 end;`

Comment: If it's a query you need you could calculate column four based on fiscal_year * 52 plus fiscal_week minus some base value

Comment: Chris - I don't think the (year+week)-(min seen year+week) can work, because it would skip a count_column value if there were a week with 0 transactions.

Comment: If you want this as a query, [`dense_rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-window.html#id-1.5.8.28.6.2.2.3.1.1.1) is what you're looking for, [here's a fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ao4nx3uNZbK2n2iWaEaVPR/0). If you want it as a column, see Chris's earlier comment.

Comment: @AdamKG that's exactly what I've been trying to achieve -- thanks!

Comment: @AdamKG - good point, I hadn't clocked that the count_column isn't simply the number of elapsed weeks, but the number of weeks that include transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by fiscal_year, fiscal_week) as count_column
from t;
```